# TypeError: url is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, url

I do:

```
var url = require('url').URL;
```

Then i:

```
backgroundImage: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg")
```

Why does it says that url is not a function?

Comment: You might want to supply some more code, like a few lines surrounding the two lines you showed.

Comment: Why would you need to use a function? CSS: `<style>someSelector { background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg") }</style>` - you do not use url() as a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing the require and just use:

```
{ backgroundImage: `url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg")` }
```

Note the **backticks** around the url("PATH-TO-IMAGE").

I don't know why you would need that import just to set a background image in CSS or like here, with a React style object.